Representability of moduli problem of elliptic curves with complex multiplication
I'd like to know whether the moduli problem for elliptic curves with complex multiplication by a fixed imaginary quadratic number field $K$ (and with suitable level structure to be picked) is representable by a scheme.
In particular, I am interested in understanding the universal object above this moduli space, which we could call the universal elliptic curve with CM by $K$.

Do you fix the quadratic field?

Yes. I edited the question, thanks.

Okay, but then I wonder, this implies the existence of a universal object living above this moduli problem. That would be the universal elliptic curve with CM by the fixed order. Is this an honest scheme of dimension 1 over this moduli problem? How can we see it, explicitly? Does it behave like, say, the universal elliptic curve over a modular curve?

You say "complex elliptic curve", but I was actually asking a bit more. Namely I would like to have a scheme, not just a complex fiber bundle. Did you mean this? Yeah I was too vague there. I guess something I'd like to know is how do you chose the level of this moduli problem as to make it representable. Like, what's a neat level in this situation?
